# MongoDB - How to Determine Date Created for Dynamically Created DBs and Collections?

Tags: mongodb, database

Is there any way to determine the date created for dynamically created mongo databases and collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For database: 
You can check the creation time for "database-name.ns" file

```
ls -l test.ns
-rw------- 1 root root 16777216 Jun 12 07:10 test.ns
```

For collection:
Most of time collection is created when you insert something into it. So, if you are not creating the collection using createCollection() command and you are using the default ObjectId for _id key, then you can get a rough estimate of the creation of the collection by knowing the time at which the first document inserted in that collection.

```
Mongo > db.test.find().sort({$natural : 1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]._id.getTimestamp()
ISODate("2013-06-12T01:40:04Z")
```

Comment: @Abhishek, when you copy the collection from one database to another, the _id is textually copied, so the second solution is not accurate enough

Comment: A new user called rubenqba posted an answer here that was meant as a reply to your answer. I've flagged it for deletion, but FYI, it read as follows: *@Abhishek, when you copy the collection from one database to another, the _id is textually copied, so the second solution is not accurate enough*. I don't know whether that means anything to you (I don't know this field at all) but thought I'd let you know.